# UK places that offer visitors a chance to wear medieval armor and clothes?

Tags: uk, clothing

I'm looking to visit places on UK that offer visitors an opportunity to wear medieval armor/clothes. Where can I find such a place?

Comment: http://www.medieval-siege-society.co.uk/Home.aspx  maybe helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[England's Medieval Festival](http://englandsmedievalfestival.com/medieval/index.html) is the largest of its kind in the UK. This year it will take place at Herstmonceux Castle East Sussex, UK on the 24th, 25th and 26th August 2013.

Held annually since 1992 over the three days of the August Bank Holiday Weekend, England's Medieval Festival at Herstmonceux Castle is Britain's largest and most magnificant celebration of the colourful Middle Ages.

**Edit**:

**Also of interest**

[Tewkesbury Medieval Festival](http://www.tewkesburymedievalfestival.org/index.htm) is now widely regarded as the largest medieval gathering of its kind in Europe, and attracts re-enactors, traders and entertainers, and visitors from all over the world.

Its central attraction is a re-enactment of the Battle of Tewkesbury, on part of the site of the original 1471 battlefield. Many of the participants including wives and children live as a medieval army in authentic medieval encampments for the whole weekend.

The event features a wide range of period entertainment, including music, dance and drama as well as a collection of fascinating characters from the past.

This year the festivities will take place on the **13-14th July 2013**.

See their [Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/TewkesburyMedievalFestival)

Answer (score 6):

A brief Google turns up [Carisbrooke Castle](http://www.english-heritage.org.uk/education/discovery-visits/carisbrooke-castle/) and the [Bodiam Castle](http://www.nationaltrustimages.org.uk/image/977453) for a start; the National Trust are big on recreating authentic experiences at their places.

If you've got some special interest I'm sure they're pretty approachable by email too, in case they only normally get the chain mail out for crushing children on school visits (how people fought in that stuff is beyond me, I can barely stand up in it for long).

Comment: I had thought it was SouthSea where I saw the costumes for anyone to try on, but perhaps it was Carisbrooke after all! Castles generally belong to English Heritage rather than the National Trust, btw.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind going on a horse, try [The Knights of Middle England](http://www.knightsofmiddleengland.com/) in Warwickshire or [The Knights Of Royal England](http://www.knightsroyal.co.uk/) in Kent.

Answer (score 3):

[Jedburgh Abbey](http://www.historic-scotland.gov.uk/propertyresults/propertyabout.htm?PropID=PL_163) in the Scottish Borders have a very family-inclusive welcome which can include getting even the kids dressed up in authentic costume - including armour, noble or peasant garb etc